# Observe child changed in realtime database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the correct way to listen for a child changed in realtime database?

This is what I try, but nothing prints when I manually update the value of billingUpdated (Int) from the web console.

```
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as! String
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ref.child("users").child(userID).child("billingUpdated").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in


            print("child changed")

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All documentation and tutorials on this are out of date with the latest version of swift ~ it seems simple but it doesn't work no matter how I write the code.

I never found the answer but here is my workaround. If you know the answer please let me know.

Workaround: loop observeSingleEvent until value is changed.

Under viewDidLoad: `waitForChange()`

The Function:

```
func waitForChange() {

        self.ref.child("users").child(self.userID).child("billingUpdated").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            let billingUpdated = snapshot.value as! Int

            if billingUpdated == 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                    print("looping again")
                    self.waitForChange()
                }
            }
            else{
                print("value has been updated")
            }
        }
    }
```

I added in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` so the loop doesn't run 100 times per second.

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out. If you want to observe `billingUpdated`, use `.value`. If yuo want to observe a JSON property **under** `billingUpdated`, you'd use `.childChanged`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  To clarify, I was trying to find out when the value for key ```billingUpdated``` was changed. The value starts as 0 (int) then when a server function completes, it updates the value to 1. I was trying to use ```.childChanged``` to listen for this value change, so I could start my next function on time.

Comment: If the JSON is `"billingUpdated": 0`, then you need a `.value` observer on `billingUpdated`, not a `.childChanged`. I'm not sure why you need a recursive `observeSingleEvent` though. I'd probably do a regular `observe` call and then stop observing once you've found the value you're looking for.